# PHP, closures and extracting parameters

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I'm not sure how to best title this so I thought I would post an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I've super-simplified this for now.

So first is the very basic class that will do the action.

```
abstract class AuditedSave extends AuditedSaveImplementation
{

    public static function run($callback = null)
    {
        return new AuditedSaveImplementation($callback);
    }

}

class AuditedSaveImplementation
{

    public function __construct(Closure $closure)
    {
        echo ' - I ran before'; // point 1, $test = 0
        $closure();
        echo ' - i ran after!'; // point 2, $test = 1
    }

}
```

Then the code that calls it.

```
$test = 0;

AuditedSave::run(function() use ($test)
{
    $test = 1;
});
```

So between point 1 and 2 as commented, the closure runs and would set the value of $test to 1. However, I want to store the value of whatever is passed as the first parameter (in this case, `$test`) as a copy of what it was at the time of function calling - which will always run, the closure then modifies it (this is the part that can be variable), and then afterwards a comparison gets made and actions happen based on differences - which will always run.

However, in order to do this, I need to be able to access the $test variable within the `__construct()` method of `AuditedSaveImplementation` without knowing what it's called.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: No, the scope of `$test` is something completely different than `AuditedSaveImplementation::__construct`. You have to rethink whatever it is you're trying to do here.

Comment: Not possible. Pass in another class with appropriate logic (e.g. `getValue()` and/or `getOriginalValue()`) instead of a simple closure. Also `$test` is always copied in the code you specified (well it's actually copy-on-write but that's not very relevant). Changing it won't affect the original variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) class `getStaticVariables` method to get params passed to closure via `use`. Like this:

```
class AuditedSaveImplementation
{

    public function __construct(Closure $closure)
    {
        echo ' - I ran before'; // point 1, $test = 0
        $closureReflection = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
        $variables = $closureReflection->getStaticVariables();
        var_dump($variables);
        $closure();
        echo ' - i ran after!'; // point 2, $test = 1
    }

}
```

**But as mentioned in the comments you should rethink how you do this.** 
It's not a good approach. Try to create a special class as was suggested in comments.

Comment: FWIW, that's a terrible solution. There should be a sane and simple interface to do this, not a bend-over-backwards solution which depends on implementation details. OP is simply on the wrong track…

Comment: I just wanted to show that this is not impossible. That everything that is passed to closure via `use` will be converted into static variables for a closure and can be extracted via reflection. But I agree that author need to rethink what he's doing here.